# Endeca 6: phrasing isn't triggered for phrases with special characters

Tags: oracle, e-commerce, commerce, endeca, phrases

The special characters are

```
,
.
+
-
```

These characters had to become searchable because of other needs.

According to Endeca guides, because they are searchable, they can be used in phrases as well ie "apple + orange".

The problem is that this doesn't seem to work, the phrasing isn't happening and the terms are treated as normal search(while the phrase has been manually tested, using quotes, in reference application to confirm the existance of results).

Did some tries with 11.2 version just to check if it is an older bug but it didn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: So these characters don't exist in your 'xxx.search_chars.xml' file and you definitely wrapped your search phrase in double quotes?

Comment: there are set as searchable in the xml file as  I mention.

Comment: So according to guides... if for example "+" is in search_chars.xml then in workbench I can create a phrase "A + B" and this will work and the phrase will be triggered for the search terms A + B .. but it doesn't.